# MS Access Row Source on table on the Front End disappears

Tags: ms-access

I have a table called t_groups which the billing type is linked with a combo box box to t_grouptypes. I have a split database and on the back-end it works without any issues, however on the front-end I am constantly having to re-add the row source field on the table design. I can literally add the row source, save, close and then re-open the table and the row source has disappeared. Not sure if it is pertinent, but I update the t_groups table with a form and over the past week I have had to re-add the row source nearly everyday. Any ideas what might be causing this and why the front end isn't staying synced to the back-end? I have tried refreshing the link to the back-end without any luck.

Working in MS Access 2016 using 2002-2003 compatible. - Thanks

Comment: I never set lookups in tables http://access.mvps.org/Access/lookupfields.htm. I build combobox on form. So I just tested this on a linked table and SURPRISE, it works! Cannot replicate the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will try that.

Comment: I decided to test again. Even after reopening db, the setup is there. Still cannot replicate the issue.